# Hide products from WooCommerce Cart / Mini Cart / Checkout / Orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When using a grouped product, I would like a number of the products to remain hidden across Cart / Mini Cart / Checkout & Orders.

I'm using [How to hide certain products on WooCommerce cart page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70755005/11987538) answer code that works perfectly for the cart but would like to expand to the others mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_visible', 'bbloomer_hide_hidden_product_from_cart' , 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_widget_cart_item_visible', 'bbloomer_hide_hidden_product_from_cart', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_visible', 'bbloomer_hide_hidden_product_from_cart', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', 'bbloomer_hide_hidden_product_from_order_woo333', 10, 2 );
    
function bbloomer_hide_hidden_product_from_cart( $visible, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    if ( $product_id == '20' ) {
        $visible = false;
    }
    return $visible;
}
    
function bbloomer_hide_hidden_product_from_order_woo333( $visible, $order_item ) {
    $product = $order_item->get_product();
    $product_id = $order_item->get_product_id();
    if ( $product_id == '20' ) {
        $visible = false;
    }
    return $visible;
}
```